# How to sum values based on same date and name

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum up Excel cells if they have the same date and name. In my case the column P is what I want to sum up. Column B is the date and column A is the name. Below is my attempt but it's not working. This formula works if I have ">=" but I want it calculate for specific day

```
=SUMIFS($P$4:$P$1000,$B$4:$B$1000,">="&Q2,$A$4:$A$1000, "="&R2)
```

Comment: In column B, are your dates just dates or is there a time element to them?  If you format the cells as "General", does it have an integer or are there decimals?

Comment: You don't need the `=` to say they are equal - Try this: `=SUMIFS($P$4:$P$1000,$B$4:$B$1000,Q2,$A$4:$A$1000, R2)`

Comment: I noticed my dates are in this format 07/03/2016 and column P is the sum of two other columns

Comment: @JinJoe, did you try my formula? It should work... Otherwise, do your dates maybe also contain times? If you want an exact match, you have to ensure the values match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If hte dates in column B are actually datetimes then you will have to bracket the date period just as if it was multiple days. Use `>=` for the start point and `<` start date plus 1 for the termination.

```
=SUMIFS($P$4:$P$1000, $A$4:$A$1000, $R$2, $B$4:$B$1000, ">="&INT(Q2), $B$4:$B$1000, "<"&INT(Q2)+1)
```

[image: sumifs_datetime_span]

To guard against Q2 being a datetime as well, the [INT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef) has been applied to strip off any time portion.

Comment: I would suppose that your date/datetimes are not true dates at all, merely text-that-looks-like-a-date. As you can clearly see, the formula works on valid data. Examine your data and fix the problem at the root.